# ¿Como centrar una imagen de fondo a medida que se redimensiona la pantalla?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

Estoy trabajando con Bootstrap una web one page, la cual trabajo imagenes tipo `background-image` dentro de un `div` de tamaño 12 (`col-lg-12`) dicho `div` tiene un alto de `640px` lo cual me cubre toda la pantalla mi fondo bg1.png (https://i.stack.imgur.com/36ds5.jpg)

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Seccion 1 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" id="S1"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Seccion 2 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" id="S2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#S1{
        background: url(bg1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 1204px;
    }
 #S2{
        background: url(bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 1204px;
    }
```

Lo que cual se ve como deseo desde un navegador, pero al verlo desde un teléfono quisiera mover al astronauta de la imagen al medio, de manera que mientras vaya re dimensionando la imagen cada vez mas chica el astronauta vaya quedando al medio de la pantalla siempre.

Comment: CSS responsive, en una media query que ocupe un % el background-size y que se posicione desde el bottom a un % del left otro % no serviria?

Comment: Para que el astronauta quede en medio es necesario posiciones relativas (con CSS) o absolutas (con JavaScript).

Comment: Entiendo lo del media queries, pero la asignación de los % no la entiendo muy bien que digamos, actualizare el código, ya que como serán secciones habrá otras imágenes que necesitarían el mismo procedimiento

Comment: @MáximaAlekz lo coloco dentro de los @media?

Comment: en vez de `background-size: cover;` usar un %, como que la imagen sea un 120%, más incluso o menos, eso dependerá de como quieras que salga, y usar `background-position: x% y%;` así podrás jugar con la posición del fondo